# select column from dataframe in which one column can have multiple name

Tags: pandas

My excel sheet contains one column whose header name can be two namely 'CITY' or 'CTY'. How to select the column in dataframe using pandas. OR operator is not working.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(data.xlsx,index_col=None)
required_data=[]
required_data=data[['CITY' or 'CTY']]
```

Comment: Use `data.loc[:, data.columns.isin(['CITY','CTY'])]`

Comment: along with that i have to select other columns a well

Comment: Add columns to list `['CITY','CTY']`

Comment: But it won't give the columns in sequence of my list...whatever column comes first in excel, it will be appearing first in dataframe

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.